# Show popup in the card

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array of objects with some data. This objects displaying in my UI like cards. I need to show some popup in the card when i am clicking on it. The problem is that when I click popup shows on all cards.

```
<li class="list-group-item" v-for="element in quened" :key="element.id">
  <div class="project">
    {{element.project}}
  </div>
  <div class="project-description">{{element.client}} {{element.price}}$</div>
  <ul class="dots-holder" @click="popup=!popup">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="popup" v-if="popup">Delete</div>
</li>
```

Maybe i should toggle the class on the `<li>`, but the problem is that i have no idea how to refer on the `<li>` in which i clicked.

Comment: you need to place your full vuejs component here

Comment: My component is too big to be placed here. What additional information do u need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to track the index of element for which you want to show popup for.
Add a data property `popupIndex`:

`popupIndex: null`

Then add a method `showPopup(index)`:

```
showPopup(index) {
  if(this.popupIndex === index)
    this.popupIndex = null;        // if you click the same element again, hide popup
  else this.popupIndex = index;    // change popup if you click other element
}
```

Keep track of element's index in your `v-for`:

```
<li class="list-group-item" v-for="(element, index) in quened" :key="element.id">
```

And your popup div should be displayed only when current list item's `index` equals to `popupIndex`:

```
<div class="popup" v-if="popupIndex === index">Delete</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/258642/